# Passing aux directory option to AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex

I use Emacs and MikTeX. With the latter comes a `PDFLaTeX` option to move clutter in a `temp-dir` directory: `-aux-directory temp-dir`. I am tentatively trying to pass it to AUCTeX with:

```lisp
(setq tex-start-options "-aux-directory temp-dir")
```

Doesn’t work! I am not very knowledgeable with AUCTeX internals. Can you give some hints and examples on `LaTeX-command`, `latex-run-command`, `tex-start-options` and `tex-start-commands` and the likes?

Comment: You can [use latexmk with AUCTeX](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8026921/789593) and pass the pdflatex option via the .latexmkrc file.

Comment: @N.N. Can you tell me what are the benefits of using Latexmk over simple Emacs/AUCTeX? 
Isn’t AUCTeX already an interface between Emacs and the LaTeX binaries?
Isn’t it possible to do in Elisp what Latexmk does in perl?

Comment: AUCTeX is such an interface and I have not that much experience with it as I have used latexmk via it instead, so I can't really say. latexmk works well (compiles as many times as needed for everything to be done) and it easy to configure.

Comment: I don't know any `-aux-directory` option for `pdflatex`, however you can set additional options to `pdflatex` customizing `LaTeX-command` variable: `M-x add-file-local-variable RET LaTeX-command RET` and set its value to `"latex -aux-directory temp-dir"` with `""` quotes and without `pdf` before `latex`, it'll be automatically prefixed if `TeX-PDF-mode` is on.